# Is there any downside for using AMP JS components for none-amp page?

Tags: amp-html

None AMP page with any amp's component works as AMP page with any AMP component. I don't see any downside as long as I don't use Google cache component. Or is there?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really any downside. You can just use AMP as a web components library.

Note that there isn't a "Google cache component". HTML pages that pass the [AMP Validator](https://validator.ampproject.org/) will be automatically served by the Google cache.

Comment: I have none AMP pages running on AMP components already and It seems to have no bad impact on website. It would be a time wasting If I would have to reproduce some of AMP components behaviour using other JS library on none AMP page.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, yes there is. As mentioned in the documentation,

> [Google AMP Cache](https://www.ampproject.org/learn/about-amp/#google-amp-cache) comes with a built-in [validation system](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/tree/master/validator) which confirms that the page is guaranteed to work, and that it doesn't depend on external resources. The validation system runs a series of assertions confirming the page’s markup meets the AMP HTML specification.

You may want to visit these links for additional insights and more information:

- [OPINION - Implementing Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP)](https://www.tunetheweb.com/blog/implementing-accelerated-mobile-pages/)
- [AMP Project Website](https://www.ampproject.org/)

Comment: OK. I don't intend to mark up the page as `amp` document. I don't intend to use the Google AMP Cache component. I only intend to use some components like the Lightbox component. So the whole page isn't AMP page but the page with some AMP components borrowed.